# Can I summon figures into a non-adjacent region?

Tags: chaos-in-the-old-world

While reading the rules for Chaos in the Old World, I came across the following paragraph on page 12 under the **Summoning Follower Figures** under the **Summoning Phase** section:

> Note that the placing player may count a given region as occupied by his own figure if he chose the last figure in that region to summon. For example, a player who picks up his last figure in Norsca in order to summon it to a different location may summon that figure to Troll Country, even if he has no figures in Troll Country or in any regions adjacent to Troll Country.

On the surface, this is rule is in place simply to allow you to 'move' a unit across the board so you can summon in regions you actually want to (if, for instance, there is a particularly debilitating Old World card in play that refuses to fall off the track). However, the first sentence caught my attention and got me thinking.

> Note that the placing player **may count a given region as occupied by his own figure if he chose the last figure in that region to summon.**

Does this allow for more advanced play tactics? For instance, would the following play (in bold) be legal?

> Khorne has one Bloodsworn in Norsca, but no units in Troll Country or Kislev
>
> - Khorne summons a Bloodsworn from Norsca into the Empire.
> - Nurgle summons a Plaguebearer into Kislev.
> - Tzeentch plays a Chaos Card in Tilea.
> - Slaanesh plays a Chaos Card in The Border Princes.
> - **Khorne summons a Bloodletter into Troll Country.**

My reasoning for believing this is legal is because Khorne was the last one to summon in Norsca - and no one else summoned into or out of Norsca during that cycle of summoning - Norsca is still counted as 'occupied by Khorne'; and therefore Khorne can summon a Bloodletter into Troll Country, as it is adjacent to a region he controls. Had another player summoned a unit into Norsca after Khorne removed his Bloodsworn, this play would not have been possible.

---

If this is a legal play, it leads to some follow-up questions:

1. If the Summoning Phase had ended with Slaanesh, would Khorne be able to summon his Bloodletter in the Summoning Phase **of the next round**?
2. If Tzeentch had played his Chaos Card in Norsca instead of Tilea, would Khorne still have been able to summon his Bloodletter?

Note that the synonymous nature of "move","place" and "summon" only applies to figures and not Chaos Cards.(Emphasis mine)

> To "summon" **a figure**, "place" **a figure** or even "move" **a figure** are all equivalent terms.

While Chaos cards are "placed" or "played", the above rule does not seem like it applies to them as it is found under the **Summoning Follower Figures** section, not the **Playing Chaos Cards** section or even the general description of the Summoning Phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a clever loophole, but I think it is an unintentional one. You've pointed out most of the reasons it's probably not intended to work like that already:

1. The rule is intended to model the movement of troops from one region to an adjacent region. It doesn't make any thematic sense to summon multiple troops to an adjacent empty region that you used to have a presence in.
2. What about the round after? And potentially the round after that?
3. How does this interact with Chaos cards?

The last two points are not defined in the rules at all, which is significant.

Most compellingly, this violates the general game design principle that it's a bad idea to make key decisions pivotal on invisible board states, stored only in player's fallible and biased memories. Once Khorne has moved their Bloodletter, everyone at the table *would have to remember* that he used to be in Norsca. Potentially they would need to remember this over multiple rounds, if Norsca remained empty. Since this state is not reflected on the board, if there was any dispute about who was where, it can't be resolved by inspection. That's just bad design.

Comment: I see your point about it being a technical oversight. Given how strong the theme is in CitOW, and the generally high standard of quality of Fantasy Flight games, it is highly unlikely that they would have expected this kind of play or designed CitOW to include it.